# PyTorch + Skorch: Make the TensorBoard callbakc keep track on manual scores defined by `EpochScoring`

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorboard, skorch

I am using [Skorch](https://github.com/skorch-dev/skorch).

I created a new score logging using the [`EpochScoring`](https://skorch.readthedocs.io/en/stable/callbacks.html#skorch.callbacks.EpochScoring) callback.
While it appears on the history log, It doesn't show on TensorBoard (I am using the [`TensorBoard`](https://skorch.readthedocs.io/en/stable/callbacks.html#skorch.callbacks.TensorBoard) callback).

Is there a way to make the TensorBoard logger be aware of that key?

I know I can do a manual callback, but I wonder if there's a simple way to get the logger save an existing key from history.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the call order matters in this case. Since both callbacks are doing their work on the end of the epoch the `TensorBoard` callback only has access to those keys in the history that were written at time of execution.

Your callback list for the net should therefore look like this:

```py
net = NeuralNet(
   ...,
   callbacks=[
       EpochScoring(...),
       TensorBoard(...),
   ],
)
```

If it was the other way around the new score would not be written.

Comment: I had this thought as well and tried it. It didn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Hmm that's strange, this is lacking some info, a reproducible example would help. Maybe the name of the value matches on of the [filter criteria](https://github.com/skorch-dev/skorch/blob/fc3758b/skorch/callbacks/logging.py#L23)? If all fails, open an issue :)